# How do you change the switch label when the state changes in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, state

I am using Material UI's [switch](https://material-ui.com/components/switches/#sizes). When the switch is on I'd like the label to say "Switch is ON" and when the switch is off I'd like the label to read "Switch is OFF". I am new to state and so would appreciate some help with achieving this!

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';

export default function SwitchesSize() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleChecked = () => {
    setChecked((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Switch size="small" checked={checked} onChange={toggleChecked} />}
        label="Switch is off"
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

Many thanks for your help :)

Katie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ternary operator with template literal string to label the switch:-

```
label={`Switch is ${checked? 'ON':'OFF'}`}
```

codesandbox:- https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-cache-4unxy

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much and for going to the extra trouble of creating a test. I love it when things are simple :)

Comment: :) <br> ya..things look good when kept simple

Answer (score 2):

Just use a ternary operator:

```
label={`Switch is ${checked ? "ON" : "OFF"}`}
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: This answer was posted first, hard to see how the other one got accepted.